# MYSQL: Insert with Select not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I can't seem to debug this issue. I am currently running to set person_id to -1, but also utilize a select statement with this person_id value.

Using this statement, I cannot find any reason online or anywhere on why this does not function:

```
Insert into Person(person_id,firstName,middleName,lastName) 
Values(-1,(Select Distinct B.firstName, B.middleName, B.lastName 
           from Ballot B 
           where B.voter_Id = 0));
```

**Result is: ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

Logically, this should function. But, I am unable to find out why. After all, the column counts definitely do match..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the `insert ... select` syntax:

```
Insert into Person(person_id, firstName, middleName, lastName) 
Select Distinct -1, firstName, middleName, lastName 
from Ballot B 
where voter_Id = 0
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02e9246e2b3ebe3f646b7de35c77b125)** (courtesy of VBokšić).

Comment: Yes he does : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02e9246e2b3ebe3f646b7de35c77b125 
:)

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Welcome @FoolishNumber! Glad that it helped out.